# Mysql query to get only 4 records in each row

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue in one mysql query. The database records are as follows.

```
id  name
1    a1
2    a1
3    a1
4    a1
5    a1
6    a1
7    a1
8    a1
```

and my expected result is as follows

```
id          name
1,2,3,4      a1
5,6,7,8      a1
```

4 records in each row

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM (SELECT
    CEIL(@rownum :=@rownum + 1 / 4) AS pageNo,
    id,
    name
FROM
    ( SELECT @rownum := 0) r, temp )  tempTable GROUP BY pageNo
```

Comment: also i believe author wants some kind of grouping by `name`